# Rails Outputting Belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite, rails-activerecord, has-many, belongs-to

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :statuses
    has_many :comments
end 
----------

class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments
    has_many :likes
end 
----------

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :status
    belongs_to :user
end
----------



 create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "profile_name"
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "avatar_file_name"
    t.string   "avatar_content_type"
    t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
  end
```

---

These are my model relationships. I am trying to output below in my index.html.erb and I am getting an error for the `first_name` part.

I tried using the console to find the user first name of each comment, which belongs to a status doing something like this `Comment.find(19).user.full_name` and it output perfectly as intended. But it doesn't work in the view file.

```
<% @statuses.each do |status| %>
    <% status.comments.each do |comment| %>
     <%= comment.user.first_name %>
    <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: are you sure that every comment has user?

Comment: Every comment belongs to an individual user. Yes, I have that in my DB.  With that said, I think I should be able to work backwards to obtain data in the user table. Previously I have this: <% @statuses.each do |status| %> <%= status.user.full_name %> <% end %> And I was able to work backwards with status to get the user's first name.

Comment: I got it. The codes are right. It's just that when I made the Comment table, there was data without a user association so the link was broken. And in view, instead of outputing blanks for entries that are broken, it outputted errors.